# Adding handlebars layouts helper to Fractal

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am trying to add the handlebars layouts helper (https://github.com/shannonmoeller/handlebars-layouts) to Fractal (http://fractal.build), but having some trouble getting it to work.

I have added it to fractal.js following the the guide located at fractal.build/guide.

I have added the needed packages (@frctl/handlebars, handlebars-helper and handlebars-layouts).

I have a file named "grid.hbs" and want to extend that in "grid-full-width.hbs".

**fractal.js**

```
const instance = fractal.components.engine();

// Using handlebars-layouts (https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-layouts)

const layouts = require('handlebars-layouts');
layouts.register(instance.handlebars);

// Using handlebars-helpers (https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers)

const helpers = require('handlebars-helpers');
helpers({
    handlebars: instance.handlebars
});
```

**grid.hbs**

```
<div class="grid">
  {{#block "content"}}
    Fallback content
  {{/block}}
</div>
```

**grid-full-width.hbs**

```
{{#extend "grid"}}
  {{#content "content"}}
    New content
  {{/content}}
{{/extend}}
```

**Output**

```
[object Object]
```

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
/*
 * Add layouts helper
 */
const hbs = require('@frctl/handlebars');

const instance = fractal.components.engine(hbs);

// Using handlebars-layouts (https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-layouts)

const layouts = require('handlebars-layouts');
layouts.register(instance.handlebars);
```

More information here: https://github.com/frctl/fractal/issues/355